# get/read JSON File from IndexedDB via Angular

Tags: json, angular, indexeddb, godot

I want to read/write a JSON-File which is saved from a Framework (GoDot 3.1) in my IndexedDB.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I use Angular and Ngx-Indexed-DB to get this file like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxIndexedDB } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-database',
  templateUrl: './database.component.html',
  styles: ['./database.component.scss']
})

export class DatabaseComponent  implements OnInit{


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

          let db = new NgxIndexedDB('/userfs');
          db.openDatabase(21, evt => {
            /* Do something */

          }).then(function(){
            db.getAll('FILE_DATA', 1).then(
                FILE_DATA => {
                    console.log(FILE_DATA);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
              });
      }
}
```

But the result is not the json-file:
[image]

I want to read and parse the json from IndexedDB and it would be nice if I can save the modified JSON-File again in IndexedDB. Can somebody help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution:

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxIndexedDB } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-database',
  templateUrl: './database.component.html',
  styles: ['./database.component.scss']
})

export class DatabaseComponent  implements OnInit{


    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
          let db = new NgxIndexedDB('/userfs');
          db.openDatabase(21, evt => {
            /* Do something */

          }).then(function(){
            db.getAll('FILE_DATA').then(
                FILE_DATA => {
                    let levelSpec = new TextDecoder().decode(FILE_DATA[1].contents)
                    console.log(levelSpec);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
              });

      }
}
```

and the result would be the parsed json file:
[image]